# MS-UIAutomation : How to get content of Excel cell

Tags: c#, .net, excel, ui-automation

I'm trying to get the content of an Excel 2016 cell with UIAutomation. I want to get the content of the cell which is under the mouse cursor position.

I have a method to capture the element under the mouse cursor position

```
private void CaptureMousePosition()
    {
        try
        {
            var cursorPosition = Cursor.Position;
            var automationElementAtCursorPosition = AutomationElement.FromPoint(new Point(cursorPosition.X, cursorPosition.Y));
            AppendElementInformation(automationElementAtCursorPosition);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error treatment
        }
    }
```

And a method to log which element is under the cursor

```
private void AppendElementInformation(AutomationElement ae)
    {
        var aeTextElement = ae.GetElement();
        var aeTextElementToString = aeTextElement != null ? aeTextElement.ToString() : "No information to log.";
        textBox1.AppendText(aeTextElementToString);
    }
```

When I try to capture the text of en excel button, there is no problem, I get this log :

> Automation Element : ControlType = ControlType.Button, Text = Fusionner et centrer, ElementBounds = 2248;107;134;23, Visible = True

But when I want to get the text of an Excel cell which is not in edition mode I get this log:

> Automation Element : ControlType = ControlType.Pane, Text = Classeur1, ElementBounds = 1680;253;1680;745, Visible = True

Aaaand, when I double-clic on the cell, I can have the text of this cell :

> Automation Element : ControlType = ControlType.Edit, Text = Hi Stackoverflow, ElementBounds = 2266;413;159;19, Visible =

Does anyone know how I can get the content of an Excel 2016 cell without double clic on the cell ? Just with the mouse cursor position.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code should work, there must be something else we are missing... Can you post your project somewhere (like GitHub)

Comment: https://github.com/Irony42/UIAutomationDetector here it is. Thanks for your reply

Comment: It works fine with Excel 2013, no need to click as soon as mouse over the cell it picks the correct data... I have not tried the "not in edition mode" yet

Comment: Yes it seems like the problem is only with Excel 2016. Thanks for the tests

Comment: How do I set the "not in edition mode" ? I haven't figured out how to do that...

Comment: I just tried [Protected View] on Excel 2013 and it can not read anything from the cell, I get: Automation Element : ControlType = ControlType.Tab no matter where I click or 2 click ... Regular View the Control changes to ControlType = ControlType.DataItem

Comment: What I call edition mode is when you double-click on a cell to add data on it

Comment: Few days ago a read a conversation between "tim" and a guy from Microsoft in the comments of this article : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winuiautomation/2016/01/01/ten-questions-on-programmatic-accessibility/
The guy cannot read the excel 2016 cells too :( It's seems difficult to do :/